# Inputs change animation to first frame showing the correct direction but not updating further

Tags: c++, animation, sfml

Inputs change the animation to the first frame so it changes the direction properly but doesn't update the repeating frames if its held.

Animation stuff in game.hpp

```cpp
private:
    sf::RenderWindow* m_pWindow = nullptr;
    Animation walkingAnimationDown;
    Animation walkingAnimationLeft;
    Animation walkingAnimationRight;
    Animation walkingAnimationUp;
    Animation* currentAnimation = &walkingAnimationDown;
    AnimatedSprite animatedSprite { sf::seconds(0.2), true, false };
```

Game.cpp

```cpp
Game::Game()
{
    //Animation Setup
    walkingAnimationDown.setSpriteSheet(*(AssetManager::getInstance()->requestTexture("celesWalking")));
    walkingAnimationDown.addFrame(sf::IntRect(32, 0, 32, 48));
    walkingAnimationDown.addFrame(sf::IntRect(64, 0, 32, 48));
    walkingAnimationDown.addFrame(sf::IntRect(32, 0, 32, 48));
    walkingAnimationDown.addFrame(sf::IntRect(0, 0, 32, 48));

    walkingAnimationLeft.setSpriteSheet(*(AssetManager::getInstance()->requestTexture("celesWalking")));
    walkingAnimationLeft.addFrame(sf::IntRect(32, 48, 32, 48));
    walkingAnimationLeft.addFrame(sf::IntRect(64, 48, 32, 48));
    walkingAnimationLeft.addFrame(sf::IntRect(32, 48, 32, 48));
    walkingAnimationLeft.addFrame(sf::IntRect(0, 48, 32, 48));

    walkingAnimationRight.setSpriteSheet(*(AssetManager::getInstance()->requestTexture("celesWalking")));
    walkingAnimationRight.addFrame(sf::IntRect(32, 96, 32, 48));
    walkingAnimationRight.addFrame(sf::IntRect(64, 96, 32, 48));
    walkingAnimationRight.addFrame(sf::IntRect(32, 96, 32, 48));
    walkingAnimationRight.addFrame(sf::IntRect(0, 96, 32, 48));

    walkingAnimationUp.setSpriteSheet(*(AssetManager::getInstance()->requestTexture("celesWalking")));
    walkingAnimationUp.addFrame(sf::IntRect(32, 144, 32, 48));
    walkingAnimationUp.addFrame(sf::IntRect(64, 144, 32, 48));
    walkingAnimationUp.addFrame(sf::IntRect(32, 144, 32, 48));
    walkingAnimationUp.addFrame(sf::IntRect(0, 144, 32, 48));

    animatedSprite.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(screenDimensions / 2.0f));

    InputManager::getInstance()->addAction(Inputs::Up, sf::Keyboard::Key::Up);
    InputManager::getInstance()->addAction(Inputs::Down, sf::Keyboard::Key::Down);
    InputManager::getInstance()->addAction(Inputs::Left, sf::Keyboard::Key::Left);
    InputManager::getInstance()->addAction(Inputs::Right, sf::Keyboard::Key::Right);
    InputManager::getInstance()->addAction(Inputs::Space, sf::Keyboard::Key::Space);
    InputManager::getInstance()->addAction(Inputs::O, sf::Keyboard::Key::O);
}

void Game::Update(float deltaTime)
{
    auto input = InputManager::getInstance();

    float speed = 80.0f;
    bool noKeyWasPressed = true;
    sf::Clock frameClock;
    sf::Time frameTime = frameClock.restart();
    sf::Vector2f movement(0.f, 0.f);

    if(input->isActionTriggered(Inputs::Space))
    {
        speed = 120.0f;
        if(input->isActionTriggered(Inputs::Up))
        {
            currentAnimation = &walkingAnimationUp;
            movement.y -= speed;
            noKeyWasPressed = false;
        }
        if(input->isActionTriggered(Inputs::Down))
        {
            currentAnimation = &walkingAnimationDown;
            movement.y += speed;
            noKeyWasPressed = false;
        }
        if(input->isActionTriggered(Inputs::Left))
        {
            currentAnimation = &walkingAnimationLeft;
            movement.x -= speed;
            noKeyWasPressed = false;
        }
        if(input->isActionTriggered(Inputs::Right))
        {
            currentAnimation = &walkingAnimationRight;
            movement.x += speed;
            noKeyWasPressed = false;
        }
    }
        else
        {
            speed = 80.0f;
            if(input->isActionTriggered(Inputs::Up))
            {
                currentAnimation = &walkingAnimationUp;
                movement.y -= speed;
                noKeyWasPressed = false;
            }
            if(input->isActionTriggered(Inputs::Down))
            {
                currentAnimation = &walkingAnimationDown;
                movement.y += speed;
                noKeyWasPressed = false;
            }
            if(input->isActionTriggered(Inputs::Left))
            {
                currentAnimation = &walkingAnimationLeft;
                movement.x -= speed;
                noKeyWasPressed = false;
            }
            if(input->isActionTriggered(Inputs::Right))
            {
                currentAnimation = &walkingAnimationRight;
                movement.x += speed;
                noKeyWasPressed = false;
            }
        }

        animatedSprite.play(*currentAnimation);
        animatedSprite.move(movement * deltaTime);

        if(noKeyWasPressed)
        {
            animatedSprite.stop();
        }
        noKeyWasPressed = true;
        animatedSprite.update(frameTime);
}

void Game::Draw()
{
    m_pWindow->clear();
    m_pWindow->draw(Background);
    m_pWindow->draw(animatedSprite);
    m_pWindow->display();
}
```

This is the animation class I'm using: https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Source:-AnimatedSprite

InputManager.cpp

```cpp
void InputManager::addAction(int id, sf::Keyboard::Key key)
{
    m_Actions[id] = key;
}

bool InputManager::isActionTriggered(int id)
{
    return sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(m_Actions[id]);
}
```

Including inputmanager because someone asked if maybe isActionTriggered is just checking for key press and not held, so might be another issue in inputs that I'm not seeing.

Comment: That's a lot of code! Please help us by trying to reduce it to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It makes your question and your problem more clear.

Comment: My bad, hopefully nothing I removed is the cause of the issue.